# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Пишу User-аутентификацию для Rails приложения.
Столкнулся с такой ошибкой (указана в заголовке вопроса)

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation

  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates :email, presence: true

  validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}, confirmation: true

  protected

    def encrypt_password
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end

    def self.authenticate(params)
      user = find_by_email(params[:email])
      if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(params[:password], user.password_salt)
        user
      else
        nil
      end
    end

end
```

accounts_controller

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(signup_params)

    if @user.save
      User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Вы успешно зарегистрировались"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def signin
    @user = User.new
  end

  def authenticate
    @user = User.authenticate(signin_params)

    if @user
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Вы успешно вошли"
    else
      render 'signin'
    end
  end

  private

    def signup_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    def signin_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
    end

end
```

Часть роутов, ответственных за все это:

```
resource :account, as: :users do
    collection do
      get 'signin', to: 'accounts#signin'
      post 'authenticate', to: 'accounts#authenticate'
    end
  end
```

форма (haml)

```
%h1 Вход

= form_for @user, url: authenticate_users_path do |f|
  %p
    = f.label :email
    = f.email_field :email
  %p
    = f.label :password
    = f.password_field :password
  %p
    = f.submit
```

Почему при оправке формы siging выдается такая ошибка?
Как правильно организовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что при неудачной авторизации вы отрисовываете форму, которая генерируется для пользователя(`@user`). При этом самого пользователя нету. Чтобы не возникала эта ошибка, перед отрисовкой вормы входа нужно создать объект класс `User`

```
def authenticate
  @user = User.authenticate(signin_params)

  if @user # Пользователь существует(@user не nil и не false)
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Вы успешно вошли"
  else  # Пользователя не существует(nil или false)
    @user = User.new # Создаем объект класса User
    render 'signin'
  end
end
```